# Date element in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

im looking to add a date criteria to my Sql but not sure how do it. 
SQL below...

```
    select 
      dsp_sku, sum(INVN_ADJMT_QTY) qty, 
      decode(pt.tran_type||pt.tran_code||pt.actn_code, '60500','Total SKU inventory','60501','Total case inventory (allocatable)','60502','Total carton inventory','60503','Total active inventory', '60504','Total transitional inventory (allocatable)','60506','Total case-pick inventory','60511','Unallocatable case inventory','60514','Unallocatable transitional inventory', '60597','Total SKU inventory - Allocatable','60598','Total SKU inventory - UnAllocatable','605TXX','Transitional inventory by type (XX=trans. type)', '605T10','Transitional inventory by type (10)','605T20','Transitional inventory by type (20)','605T30','Transitional inventory by type (30)', '605T40','Transitional inventory by type (40)','605T0','Transitional inventory by type (0)','605T99','Transitional inventory by type (99)', '605LPN','Case Inventory by lock code (PN)','605LRC','Case Inventory by lock code (RC)','605LQA','Case Inventory by lock code (QA)','605LQH','Case Inventory by lock code (QH)', '605LEX','Case Inventory by lock code (EX)','605LRW','Case Inventory by lock code (RW)','605LDM','Case Inventory by lock code (DM)','605LWD','Case Inventory by lock code (WD)', '605LQU','Case Inventory by lock code (QU)','605LCH','Case Inventory by lock code (CH)','605LSD','Case Inventory by lock code (SD)','605LBL','Case Inventory by lock code (BL)', '605LCC','Case Inventory by lock code (CC)','605LML','Case Inventory by lock code (ML)','605LXX','Case Inventory by lock code (XX=lock code)' ) STATUS, 
      pt.tran_type||pt.tran_code||pt.actn_code code_blend
    from PIX_TRAN pt
      inner join item_master im on
        im.sku_id = pt.sku_id 
    where
      tran_type = '605' 
    --and tran_code = '01'
      --and actn_code
      and whse = 'PH3' 
    --and trunc(pt.create_date_time) like trunc(sysdate) - 1
      and (
(im.dsp_sku ='85865') or
(im.dsp_sku ='86111') or
(im.dsp_sku ='173016') or
(im.dsp_sku ='176630') or
(im.dsp_sku ='72204064')
)

    group by 
      dsp_sku, tran_type||tran_code||actn_code
    order by 
      code_blend, dsp_sku
```

In the section it is looking at the SKU,

```
 and (
(im.dsp_sku ='85865') or
(im.dsp_sku ='86111') or
(im.dsp_sku ='173016') or
(im.dsp_sku ='176630') or
(im.dsp_sku ='72204064')
)
```

im looking to add a date element to it. the purpose off the query is to see if there was inventory in the building on a certain day, so I want to be able to say like `(im.dsp_sku = '85864' (then how ever you would have it check for the specific day)` the thing is I need to check each SKU against a certain date so I cant do one massive search each SKU has its own date that needs checked and I have about 11k SKU's to check.
Any insight is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
 (im.dsp_sku ='85865' and trunc(pt.create_date_time) = '05/05/2019')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to apply `TRUNC` over the date column as it would cause an existing index on the date column if any, to be unused, thus making it less performant.

Rewrite your `TRUNC` statement as

```
pt.create_date_time  >= DATE '2019-05-05' AND 
pt.create_date_time  <  DATE '2019-05-05' + 1
```

If you want to pass the value of date in a desired format, use `TO_DATE`, but only on right hand side.

```
pt.create_date_time  >= TO_DATE( '05/05/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
pt.create_date_time  <  TO_DATE( '05/05/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') + 1 
                                          --or mm/dd/yyyy
```